# How to embed a flv video into a web page?

Tags: video, flash, html, flv

I want to let my visitors to watch my video directly at my web page. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2):

On [this page](http://www.walkernews.net/2008/01/11/how-to-embed-flv-flash-in-wordpress-or-html/) I found the following code:

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
       codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0"
       width="480" height="360">
<param name="flashvars" value="YOUR_FILE.FLV&YOUR_FILE.JPG" />
<param name="movie" value="YOUR_FILE.SWF" />
<embed src="YOUR_FILE.SWF" width="480" height="360"
       type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
       pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"
       flashvars="YOUR_FILE.FLV&image=YOUR_FILE.JPG" />
</object>
```

Obviously replace `YOUR_FILE.FLV`, `YOUR_FILE.JPG` and `YOUR_FILE.SWF` with the URLs of your video and placeholder jpg.

You'll find asking this sort of question on [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) will get you a quicker and better response.

Comment: +1, for Stackoverflow: also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43992/how-to-safely-embed-any-flash-file-swf

Answer (score 1):

We know FLV can not be played directly in the web page. It must be embed into a player. Here the player indicates the SWF files. With the player, you can start playing video, pause the video playback, play the video with full screen or adjust the volume.